# Retrieving follower and followee (friend) counts using Twitter API

Tags: social-network-analysis, twitter

I want to retrieve Twitter users' **follower** and **followee (friend) count** using `Twitter API`. (I  am reluctant with using a `crawler` since I need this data for research purposes) However, I was only able to find [**get_friend_list DOC**](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-friends-list) which returns the whole list of followers.

I just want to get the number of followers and follweees not the while list of follower id (*since this will require me to use more POST requests for Twitter API*)

Could someone help me how to retrieve follower count with Twitter id (or username)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using [`GET users/show`](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-show) from Twitter API.

The details of `User object` which can be retrieved with this `GET request` can be founded in [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/user-object).